# Tree complexity in boosted regression trees

Tags: r, boosting, supervised-learning

In boosting regress trees, there are many tuning parameters and I am interested in the tree complexity also called the interaction depth while using the R package GBM:

I want to understand more about the tree complexity. I work in the agriculture domain where there are interactions between different climate variables resulting in yield. For e.g. effect of drought gets intensified if temperature is high causing further reduction in crop yield which to me seems there is two way interaction.

When running the gbm package in R, does the agrument `tree.complexity` be set to 2 to model two way interaction? What happens if I change the `tree.complexity` to 3?

**EDIT**
I am just trying to understand whether specifying tree complexity = 2 is same as specifying an interaction term like this `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2)` in R.

Comment: Chapter 10 of *Elements of Statistical Learning* covers boosting and additive trees. https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print12.pdf

Comment: Just one thing: Implementations of boosted trees typically offer many tuning parameters, not just tree depth and learning rate.

Comment: I disagree with the premise.  A boosted tree is a series ensemble of trees.  The parameter for a single tree can be stochastic columns or rows, max splits, min points per leaf, double binomial, what is your split metric (gini, sd, other) and the list goes on.  There are about 10 critical ones for CART.  There is stochastic learning (subsampling in row and column), learning rate, max trees.  Are you asking about "complexity" related to a single package?

Comment: I have changed the question slightly to reflect your comments